# How to make list of tuple from list of list?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

How do I convert this list of lists:

```
[['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['0', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['1', '6'], ['1', '7'], ['1', '9'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '6'], ['2', '8'], ['2', '9']]
```

To this list of tuples:

```
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [0, 4, 6, 7, 9]), (2, [0, 3, 6, 8, 9])]
```

I am unsure how to implement this next step? (I can't use dictionaries,
sets, deque, bisect module. You can though, and in fact should, use .sort or sorted functions.)

Here is my attempt:

```
network= [['10'], ['0 1'], ['0 2'], ['0 3'], ['1 4'], ['1 6'], ['1 7'], ['1 9'], ['2 3'], ['2 6'], ['2 8'], ['2 9']]
network.remove(network[0])
friends=[]

for i in range(len(network)):
    element= (network[i][0]).split(' ')
    friends.append(element)


t=len(friends)
s= len(friends[0])
lst=[]

for i in range(t):
    a= (friends[i][0])
    if a not in lst:
        lst.append(int(a))
        for i in range(t):
            if a == friends[i][0]:
                b=(friends[i][1])
                lst.append([b])
print(tuple(lst))
```

It outputs:

```
(0, ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], 0, ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], 0, ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], 1, ['4'], ['6'], ['7'], ['9'], 1, ['4'], ['6'], ['7'], ['9'], 1, ['4'], ['6'], ['7'], ['9'], 1, ['4'], ['6'], ['7'], ['9'], 2, ['3'], ['6'], ['8'], ['9'], 2, ['3'], ['6'], ['8'], ['9'], 2, ['3'], ['6'], ['8'], ['9'], 2, ['3'], ['6'], ['8'], ['9'])
```

I am very close it seems, not sure what to do??

Comment: look up list comprehension & defaultdict, try something, if it works, great. else post your attempt, and the community will be glad to help

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method:

```
l = [['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['0', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['1', '6'], ['1', '7'], ['1', '9'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '6'], ['2', '8'], ['2', '9']]
a=set(i[0] for i in l)
b=list( (i,[]) for i in a)
[b[int(i[0])][1].append(i[1]) for i in l]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[('0', ['1', '2', '3']), ('1', ['4', '6', '7', '9']), ('2', ['3', '6', '8', '9'])]
```

## Alternate Answer (without using set)

```
l = [['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['0', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['1', '6'], ['1', '7'], ['1', '9'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '6'], ['2', '8'], ['2', '9']]
a=[]
for i in l:
    if i[0] not in a:
        a.append(i[0])
b=list( (i,[]) for i in a)
[b[int(i[0])][1].append(i[1]) for i in l]
print(b)
```

also outputs

```
[('0', ['1', '2', '3']), ('1', ['4', '6', '7', '9']), ('2', ['3', '6', '8', '9'])]
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, is there another simpler way without using set..I am unable to in this circumstance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l = [['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['0', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['1', '6'], ['1', '7'], ['1', '9'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '6'], ['2', '8'], ['2', '9']]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, dtype=np.int)
s = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
list(zip(s.index, s))
```

Output:

```
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 6, 7, 9]), (2, [3, 6, 8, 9])]
```